# Slick grid too slow even for loading 1000 records

Tags: javascript, php, css, json, slickgrid

I am quite new to use slickgrid and am trying to load 1200 records using it. The time taken to load the data is around 6sec (this is quite big). How to reduce the loading time from the server? I have seen some of the sample examples in SO but none of them helped me.

One approach would be initially loading first 100 records as soon as possible and then loading the remaining items in the bottom. How can I achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
<script>

var grid;
var columns = [
{ id: "Class", name: "Class", field: "Class", formatter: alignFormatter1},
{ id: "Number", name: "Number", field: "Number", formatter: alignFormatter2},
{ id: "Subject", name: "Subject", field: "Subject",formatter: alignFormatter3},
{ id: "Student", name: "Student", field: "Student", formatter: alignFormatter4},
{ id: "Date", name: "Date", field: "Date", formatter: alignFormatter5},
 ];

 function dayFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  //return value + ' days';
}

  function dateFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  //return value.getMonth() + '/' + value.getDate() + '/' + value.getFullYear();
}

function alignFormatter1(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  return "<span style='margin-left: 32px;'>"+dataContext.Class+"</span>";
}

function alignFormatter2(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  return "<span style='margin-left: 22px;'>"+dataContext.Number+"</span>";
}

function alignFormatter3(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  return "<span style='margin-left: 10px;'>"+dataContext.Subject+"</span>";
}

function alignFormatter4(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  return "<span style='margin-left: 32px;'>"+dataContext.Student+"</span>";
}

function alignFormatter5(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  return "<span style='margin-left: 95px;'>"+dataContext.Date+"</span>";
}

var options = {
enableCellNavigation: true,
enableColumnReorder: true,
multiColumnSort: true,
editable: true
};


$(function () {

var MS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var data = [];

var listdata = <?php echo json_encode($storeData)?>;
console.log(listdata);

for (var i = 0; i < listdata.length; i++) {

  data[i] = {
    Class:  listdata[i][0],
    Number: listdata[i]['1'],
    Subject: listdata[i]['2'],
    Student: listdata[i]['3'],
    Date: listdata[i]['4'],
  };

}



grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());
grid.registerPlugin( new Slick.AutoTooltips({ enableForHeaderCells: false }) );
grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector); 

grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  var cols = args.sortCols;
  data.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
    for (var i = 0, l = cols.length; i < l; i++) {
      var field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
      var sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
      var value1 = dataRow1[field], value2 = dataRow2[field];
      var result = (value1 == value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1 : -1)) * sign;
      if (result != 0) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    return 0;
  });
  grid.invalidate();
  grid.render();
});
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var awidth,aheight,newheight;
awidth=$(window).width();
aheight=$(window).height();
newheight=aheight*0.9-150;
newheight = newheight | 0;
document.getElementById('myGrid').setAttribute("style","height:"+newheight+"px;");

</script>
```

NOTE: Based on the the suggestion from the comments, the php coded is added up

```
 <?php 

$sql        = "SELECT * FROM university_marks WHERE 1 ".$where. "ORDER BY Date desc";
//echo $sql;
$searchdetails = mysql_query( $sql );
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($searchdetails);



    $storeData = array();
    $i= 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($searchdetails)) {

        $storeData[$i][] = $row['ID'];
        $storeData[$i][] = $row['1'];
        $storeData[$i][] = $row['2'];
        $storeData[$i][] = $row['3'];
        $storeData[$i][] = $row['4'];
        $storeData[$i][] = $row['5'];

 $sql4    = "SELECT * FROM `faculty_address` WHERE id = $id and address!= '' ";
            $adddetails4 = mysql_query($sql4);
            $facultydetails4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($adddetails4);
            $num_rows5 = mysql_num_rows($adddetails4);
            if($num_rows5 > 0){
            $storeData[$i][] ='Filled';
                }
            else{
                $storeData[$i][] ='Notfilled';
            }

 $sql5        = "SELECT * FROM `students_attendence` WHERE id = '".$id."' AND ID_course='".$course."'";
            $adddetails5 = mysql_query($sql5);
            $csipdetails5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($adddetails5);
            $num_rows6 = mysql_num_rows($adddetails5);
            if($num_rows6 > 0){
            $storeData[$i][] ='Filled';
                }
            else{
                $storeData[$i][] ='Notfilled';
            }       

 $sql6        = "SELECT * FROM `students_marks` WHERE CA_ID = $id AND column1!= '' AND column2 !='' AND column3 !='' ";
            $adddetails31 = mysql_query($sql31);
            $studetails31 = mysql_fetch_assoc($adddetails31);
            $num_rows41 = mysql_num_rows($adddetails31);
            if($num_rows41 > 0){
            $storeData[$i][] ='Filled';
                }
            else{
                $storeData[$i][] ='Notfilled';
            }   

        $i++;
    }



?>
```

From the suggestions in the comments, i got the bottleneck issue while executing the sql queries in php. The SQL queries are taking too much of time which resulting in the delay. I need these values in filling the column data in slickgrid ($sql4, $sql5, $sql6, )

Comment: You are talking about reducing time on server, but I see only frontend code, you should add some code of loading in php too, mention if you use ORM or how do you load data, etc.

Comment: Check how long the actual data part takes, and then how long it takes the JS to run. Basically, find your bottleneck

Comment: @Eakethet, I just added my PHP code now. Could you kindly have a look into it

Comment: @Farkie, I just got the problem which is taking too much of time. It's the sql queries in the php code. Could you please have a look into the edited question and let me know how to overcome it.

Comment: @John You are running too much queries, you run 3 queries for every result from first query, thats really alot. Read something about "JOINS" in sql. You should be able to take it down to just one query.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify here, this is not a SlickGrid issue.

The best way to initially determine where the problem is, is to load the page up in Chrome, open the developer tools (ctrl-shift-I) and check the 'network' tab. This will show you the page source timings within the page load.

It appears that the problem is indeed on the server side, if you are retrieving 1200 records and then running 3 queries against each, then you are running 3600 separate queries against the database. No wonder it takes 6 seconds!
As suggested by @Eakethet, take some time out to learn some basic SQL and rewrite all this into a single query. You may also need to add some database indexes to speed the lookup of the related data. If all this is done, you should be able to get response well under 500 ms.